# AT&T XOR argument at radare2

Tags: radare2, disassemblers, crackme

Recently I faced with strange (in my opinion) behavior of radare2.

I have been reading the [Artificial truth](https://dustri.org/b/defeating-crackme03-with-radare2.html) blog post about [Hacking bits](http://hackingbits.github.io/blog/crackme-03/) with this [crackme](https://github.com/geyslan/crackmes/blob/master/src/crackme.03.asm).

In an article Julien used ***Intel*** syntax,
but I choose ***AT&T***.

So I started disassemble crackme:

```
$ r2 ./crackme.03.32
```

Set syntax to intel, block size to 10 bytes and seek to needed address and print disassemble:

```
[0x00010020]> e asm.syntax = intel
[0x00010020]> b 10
[0x00010020]> s 0x0010112
[0x00010112]> pd
```

Output was:

```
       0x00010112    80f2ac         xor dl, 0xac
       0x00010115    eb02           jmp 0x10119
```

But when I changed syntax to ATT:

```
[0x00010112]> e asm.syntax = att
[0x00010112]> pd
```

I received that:

```
       0x00010112    80f2ac         xorb $-0x54, %dl
       0x00010115    eb02           jmp 0x10119
```

In the [source code](https://github.com/geyslan/crackmes/blob/master/src/crackme.03.asm#L159) of crackme we can find that value of argument is 0xac *(xor dl, 0xac)*.

### So, actually, question:

Why **80 f2 ac** translate to the same opcodes, but with different arguments for AT&T and Intel syntax.

***Why 0xac became -0x54?***

---

```
$ r2 -version
radare2 0.10.0-git 8247 @ linux-little-x86-64 git.0.9.9-148-gd5f2661
commit: d5f2661cbe1a32bc26490bd7a1864ef45907aaea build: 2015-06-26
```

Comment: It's a matter of notation of a single byte *only*. The *byte* value `0xAC` can be written as `-0x54`.

Comment: You should learn about representation of signed and unsigned values; this will make it clear immediately. Interpreting the first bit of `0xac` as a sign bit, not a value bit, will result in `-0x54`, as `0xac`+`0x54`=`0x100`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I have thought about signed and unsigned values.

Comment: Now here is the current output after changing the syntax with att in radare2. 

`xorb $0xac, %dl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was signed and unsigned question.

The way to change the signedness is by negating it, which is NOTing all bits of that number and incrementing it by 1

```
>>> 256 - (~(-0x54)+1)
172
>>> hex(172)
'0xac'
>>>
```